# pod FacebookShare issues

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using Xcode 10.1, deployment target 9.0. And I'm trying to add:

```
  pod 'FacebookCore'
  pod 'FacebookLogin'
  pod 'FacebookShare'
```

To the project. After running `pod install` I have this issue:

[image]

I was trying to

```
rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"
rm -rf "pwd/Pods/"
pod update
```

And Also delete the project folder in `Derived Data`, but nothing happened. What is wrong?

Comment: These `Pods` work fine in `Xcode 10.1` and deployment target 9.0, your problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to resolve this issue is follow these steps

1) click on project or in product in xcode then click on manage scheme

2) after uncheck your project and check your pod u have installed

3) Build your application with your pod

4) After again change your scheme and uncheck pod and check your app this will works , i added images to explain this :)

[image: this is the way]

[image: then this]

Comment: did u build the app with pod ?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we want to update any Pod file, if we fire 'pod update' command in terminal, then other Pods are also getting updated. In this way, If we did any change in any Pod framework, then we probably lost all changes.

So, in above case, just follow steps:

```
Step 1 - Remove all 3 Facebook Pods from Podfile
Step 2 - Fire 'pod install' command in Terminal
Step 3 - Again add 3 Facebook Pods in Podfile
Step 4 - Again fire 'pod install' command in Terminal.
```

You are done. Just clear project and build it again. New Pods will be updated.

FYI. There is one linking issue in Facebook 4.39 Pod framework, so just use 4.38 pod version which is working properly.

Thanks.

Comment: this not working. Also I've trying to downgrade to `pod 'FacebookShare', '~> 0.4.0'`